# Django testing using GeoDjango + PostGIS

Tags: django, unit-testing, postgis, geodjango

Recently I add GeoDjango to my project and install PostGIS 2.0 to implement it, but now when I try to run `manage.py test` I get the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_database" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_database', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
DatabaseError: type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry"
LINE 24:     "location" geometry(POINT,432
```

In my settings.py I set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

Adding helpful outputs

```
./manage.py test --verbosity=3
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_database')...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_database" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_database', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_flatpage_sites
Creating table django_flatpage
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table celery_taskmeta
Creating table celery_tasksetmeta
Creating table djcelery_intervalschedule
Creating table djcelery_crontabschedule
Creating table djcelery_periodictasks
Creating table djcelery_periodictask
Creating table djcelery_workerstate
Creating table djcelery_taskstate
Creating table notification_noticetype
Creating table notification_noticesetting
Creating table notification_noticequeuebatch
Creating table registration_registrationprofile
Creating table south_migrationhistory
Creating table authtoken_token
Creating table social_auth_usersocialauth
Creating table social_auth_nonce
Creating table social_auth_association
Creating table accounts_clientprofile
Creating table locations_location
DatabaseError: type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry"
LINE 24:     "location" geometry(POINT,4326),
```

The database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'database',                      
        'USER': 'database',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

The model with the PointField:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Add helpful outputs from 1. `python manage.py test --verbosity=3` 2. Your postgres log file, and the model that has the location field.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a db/template `template_postgis` in your database. See [Testing a GeoDjango app with a PostGIS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730189/testing-a-geodjango-app-with-a-postgis-database/24730318#24730318)