# Heroku won't allow me to rename DB and thus can't run Django unit tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, heroku

I'm trying to run Django tests via `python manage.py test --settings="app.test-settings"`

**Settings File Below**

```
#Testing On Heroku DB 
from changeaddress.settings import *
import dj_database_url
TEST_DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.getenv('TEST_DATABASE_URL'))
}
TEST_DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
REDIS_CACHE_TYPE = None
POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 0, 3)
TEST_RUNNER = 'changeaddress.test_suite_runner.HerokuTestSuiteRunner'
```

When running a test I'm getting the above error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in
__exit__ six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 51,
in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geography" does not exist LINE 17:  "area" geography(MULTIPOLYGON,4326),
```

I found this [Testing a GeoDjango app with a PostGIS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730189/testing-a-geodjango-app-with-a-postgis-database/28089840#28089840) but I'm not able to make any changes to the "template_postgis" as I do not have privileges.

I can't use `sqlite` because I have modules that utilize the POSTGIS options of the db.  Which through errors and kill the tests...

Is there a way to do this without blowing up the Django source code?
As I'd need to get this to be able to run on **CircleCI**.

**UPDATE**

**There isn't a good way to make this work with HEROKU.  For the moment I've pushed everything to be tested only on Circle CI.**

As always thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you are on the right way. The continuous integration is the way to go for testing your code before send it to production. Heroku did a great work with its buildpacks, but its not a good environment to testing things that are not "usual" on web development.

About your problem on PostGIS on heroku, look this comment from Heroku documentation:

> PostGIS is available in public beta. The beta is available on all
>   Production tier databases and **currently supports PostGIS version 2.0**.
>   **It is not available on the Dev or Basic Hobby tier plans**. PostGIS is
>   only available with Postgres 9.2 databases provisioned after April 20,
>   2013 and all Postgres 9.3 database. To enable PostGIS once connected
>   to your PostgreSQL 9.2 database run: 
>   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

Make sure you are not using a version above 2.0 and not running on a development or basic database environment.

Again, IMHO you should do this on the circle-ci continuous integration environment and then push the resulting artifacts to Heroku.